# Recommendations for ROS 2 Humble and Gazebo demo for robot arm?

Tags: gazebo, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for a working demo using ROS 2 Humble and Gazebo for a robot arm.  It seems the classic demos (e.g. RRBot) and MoveIt are all using kinematic simulations with just RViz.

Does anyone have a preferred demo that works "out of the box" for ROS 2 Humble and Gazebo, and preferably with a ROS 2 controls and Moveit setup as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413181/recommendations-for-ros-2-humble-and-gazebo-demo-for-robot-arm?/) by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2023-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2023-03-09**:
So I asked what I thought was a simple question, but somehow missed the recent simulation hell that has descended.  So there are out of date Gazebo classic simulations, then some Ignition simulation work during ROS 2 conversions, but that is now back to new Gazebo (to replace Ignition), which cannot run along side Gazebo "classic".  None of which are fully integrated with fast evolving ROS 2 controllers.  So I'm more confused than ever about the best path forward for new development and what the transition path should look like as we convert old packages to ROS 2.  Should we convert simulation to "new Gazebo (Ign?), or continue using Gazebo "classic".  Is there some document that provides the current "best practices" for ROS 2 Humble and Rolling?  It seems things are much less stable than I presumed, and I'm more confused about how to advise the new students I'm onboarding.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2023-03-09**:
https://community.gazebosim.org/t/a-new-era-for-gazebo/1356

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2023-03-09**:
https://discourse.ros.org/t/the-future-of-ros-simulation-2025/11538/2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might find either of these interesting:

- https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Gazebo_Simulation for `gazebo classic`, or
- https://github.com/AndrejOrsula/panda_ign_moveit2 for `ignition gazebo`

Not sure how stable/recently updated these are though. Bear in mind that these might not be that far from the "kinematic" simulations in RViz as they might appear, depending on the controllers that they use under the hood (as I discuss a bit in [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/412712/revolute-joint-disobeying-limits-in-gazebo/)). But depending on what you need, they might be sufficient.

Edit:

- here's another, potentially better maintained option for a Kuka LBR arm using ROS2 (up to Humble) and Gazebo (Classic?) https://github.com/KCL-BMEIS/lbr_fri_ros2_stack

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2023-03-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2023-03-09**:
I looked at the Panda one, but it is older Ignition simulation, which stimulated my comment on my main question.

**Comment by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) on 2023-03-12**:
Neither of the UR simulation packages work for me yet.

Re the Gazebo "Classic" see

https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Gazebo_Simulation/issues/19

I will probably push forward toward Ignition (which of course confusingly is now just called Gazebo) because "Classic" is EOL in 2025.

The UR packages have been working well for me otherwise but I don't think simulation is a high maintainer priority with all the other changes going on, and I expect some of the ros2_control evolution is keeping other robot package maintainers similarly busy keeping the real robots working well.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An update to my above comment about the UR Gazebo Classic simulation. The issue there was related to the ODE parameter `fmax`, see

https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Gazebo_Simulation/issues/19#issuecomment-1481929619

and more detail here:

https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Description/pull/55

Still don't exactly know how it should be fixed formally, but there is a workaround if you modify the `ur_description` package to add friction to the joint `<dynamics>` tags in the URDF.

This friction parameter passes through to the ODE physics engine and sets `fmax`, and then the UR Gazebo simulation works.

I also did seem to get a working UR Ignition simulation on ROS Rolling natively installed on Ubuntu Jammy, but I didn't dig much into whether everything was working.

---

Originally posted by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) with karma: 337 on 2023-04-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1